# rspec appending nil to my session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Using Rails 3.2.11, Rspec with Capybara

In my controller spec, I am creating a session[:return_to] as follows:

```
session[:return_to] = (FULL_ROOT_URL + '/users/' + @user.id.to_s).to_s
```

The value returned when I print out session[:return_to] in the debugger is: (this is an example value but always appends nil):

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/users/1nil
```

Do you see how it appends nil to the string? And does not even return the value as a string?

I'm a bit confused and can't figure this one out on my own...

Comment: which line is after the print?

Comment: Yeah, I suspect you have some other code writing out the nil